# Mongodb: строгая типизация

Tags: php, mongodb

Столкнулся с такой проблемой при изучении mongo: в MongoDB запросы обладают строгой типизацией. То есть следующие два документа не будут идентичны:

```
{"age" : "28"}
{"age" : 28}
```

Как можно сделать так, чтобы при запросе `{"age" : 28}` сервер выдавал результаты и запроса `{"age" : "28"}` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чуть изменить запрос:

```
db.table.find( {"age" : {$in: [28,"28"]} } );
```

Comment: Хм... неплохой вариант, спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

MongoDB сама не преобразовывает типы. Делайте это сами в php до сохранения.

```
$age = intval($age);
```

Comment: Не вариант, данные уже сохранены, их более 100т. :(

Comment: @Jeix, что мешает взять и отнормализовать?

Comment: @Etki, ну, например, лень xD

Comment: @Jeix, это непрофессионально